# How do I generate serial wif key, the program generate only one key in python

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, private-key

How do I generate a serial wif key which contains at least 1000 keys? The code I used generates only one key and I want more. Please can you help me out? I try to change it but it still works the same. All I want is to generate more of it.

The code I used to generate the 1 wif keys can be found below,

```py
import os
import hashlib

def run(name):
    print("{} started!".format(name))

def sha256(data):
    digest = hashlib.new("sha256")
    digest.update(data)
    return digest.digest()


def ripemd160(x):
    d = hashlib.new("ripemd160")
    d.update(x)
    return d.digest()


def b58(data):
    B58 = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    if data[1] == 1:
        return "1" + b58(data[1:])

    x = sum([v * (256 ** i) for i, v in enumerate(data[::-1])])
    ret = ""
    while x > 0:
        ret = B58[x % 58] + ret
        x = x // 58

    return ret


class Point:
    def __init__(self,
        x=0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798,
        y=0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8,
        p=2**256 - 2**32 - 2**9 - 2**8 - 2**7 - 2**6 - 2**4 - 1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.p = p


    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__radd__(other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__rmul__(other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        n = self
        q = None

        for i in range(256):
            if other & (1 << i):
                q = q + n
            n = n + n

        return q

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return self
        x1 = other.x
        y1 = other.y
        x2 = self.x
        y2 = self.y
        p = self.p

        if self == other:
            l = pow(2 * y2 % p, p-2, p) * (3 * x2 * x2) % p
        else:
            l = pow(x1 - x2, p-2, p) * (y1 - y2) % p

        newX = (l ** 2 - x2 - x1) % p
        newY = (l * x2 - l * newX - y2) % p

        return Point(newX, newY)

    def toBytes(self):
        x = self.x.to_bytes(32, "big")
        y = self.y.to_bytes(32, "big")
        return b"\x04" + x + y




def getWif(privkey):
    wif = b"\x80" + privkey
    wif = b58(wif + sha256(sha256(wif))[:4])
    return wif


if __name__ == "__main__":
    randomBytes = os.urandom(32)
    print(" " + getWif(randomBytes))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you repeat your code 1000 times in a loop?

Comment: i'm gonna try some new way to solve puzzle.

Comment: You don't need a "new way".  Your way works fine.  You just need to call your function in a loop 1000 times, as mkrieger1 suggested.

Comment: please can you show me to add this function?

Comment: You already have it, it's called `getWif`.

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Solution: don't try to call a `None` object like a function.